# Is there a way to parallelise this loop over a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got 8 columns in my dataframe where the values can range from the numbers 1 to 99. I'm trying to create additional columns i.e. '1_observed', '2_observed', '3_observed'... '99_observed', depending on whether any of those numbers are appearing in that observation.

The code I'm running works, but it's very slow as I'm running a loop within a loop.

```
for index in df[observed_nos].index:
    for num in range(1,100):
        if num in df[observed_nos].iloc[index].values:
            df[f'{num}_observed'][index] = '1'
        else:
            df[f'{num}_observed'][index] = '0'
```

I am not massively experienced with pandas, is there a way to run this faster / parallelise it?

EDIT:
sample dataframe as below:

```
data = [[12,14,33,45,22,33,86,56],
        [78,12,52,1,99,22,4,19],
        [15,11,7,23,30,19,63,71],
        [2,14,52,36,17,95,8,39],
        [1,4,31,42,72,23,67,15],
        [92,28,32,52,77,19,55,10],
        [42,16,64,25,92,11,26,36],
        [12,21,38,17,90,32,41,74],
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['N1','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8'])
```

this results in the following df

```
.   N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6  N7  N8
0   12  14  33  45  22  33  86  56
1   78  12  52  1   99  22  4   19
2   15  11  7   23  30  19  63  71
3   2   14  52  36  17  95  8   39
4   1   4   31  42  72  23  67  15
5   92  28  32  52  77  19  55  10
6   42  16  64  25  92  11  26  36
7   12  21  38  17  90  32  41  74
```

the output i'm trying to get to would be as follows:

```
    N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6  N7  N8  1_  2_  3_  4_  5_  6_  7_  8_  9_
0   12  14  33  45  22  33  86  56  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   78  12  52  1   99  22  4   19  1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2   15  11  7   23  30  19  63  71  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   2   14  52  36  17  95  8   39  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
4   1   4   31  42  72  23  67  15  1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
5   92  28  32  52  77  19  55  10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   42  16  64  25  92  11  26  36  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   12  21  38  17  90  32  41  74  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

(I've truncated the above example to only check for the occurrences of numbers 1 - 9, to make it easier to view)

Comment: An example DataFrame would be great. Can you please provide some sample data with expected output?

Comment: Hi cs9 - have edited my question above - I'm providing a much smaller sample dataframe, but even this runs pretty slowly on my laptop

Comment: firstly, we dont really know what you want to achieve, we only konw how you tried to solve your problem, ie [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

secondly check out [pandas performance enhancement](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html) guide

Comment: Take a look at `(df.values[:,None] == np.arange(10)[:,None]).any(axis=1).astype(np.uint8)`, this should get you some part of the way there.

Comment: @die_troller Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @divakar, I saw your solution - the solution provided by '@sekky worked for me, and I implemented it before I saw your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I played around a bit with pandas and found another solution that might work for you. Although it does not provide 0 and 1, but instead Trua and False (you might have to modify the data to fit your needs).

Also, you might want to check if this code is in fact any faster than yours:

```
rand = np.random.RandomState(42)
items = rand.randint(1, 100, 800).reshape((100, 8))

df = pd.DataFrame(items)

for n in range(1, 100):
    df[f'{n}_observed'] = df[df == n].any(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Hope this suggestion helps you!

Comment: Amazing, that worked - much MUCH appreciated, that was multiple orders of magnitude faster!

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are positive numbers, you can just treat them as indices on a 2D mapping grid. So, use a boolean grid array, use the given values as column indices and for each row of the input dataframe, use the same row indices. Now, with these row and col indices, assign `True` values there. This grid will also be your final array, when viewed as `int` array. So, the implementation would look something like this -

```
def presence_df(df, start=1, stop=99, str_postfix='_'):
    c = df.to_numpy()
    n = len(c)
    id_ar = np.zeros((n,stop+1), dtype=bool)
    id_ar[np.arange(n)[:,None],c] = 1
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(id_ar[:,start:stop+1].view('i1'))
    df1.columns = [str(i) + str_postfix for i in range(start,stop+1)]
    df_out = pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1)
    return df_out
```

Sample run -

```
In [41]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(8,10)))

In [42]: presence_df(df,start=1, stop=9)
Out[42]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  1_  2_  3_  4_  5_  6_  7_  8_  9_
0  6  1  4  4  8  4  6  3  5  8   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
1  7  9  9  2  7  8  8  9  2  6   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
2  9  5  4  1  4  6  1  3  4  9   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1
3  2  4  4  4  8  1  2  1  5  8   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
4  4  3  8  3  1  1  5  6  6  7   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
5  9  5  2  5  9  2  2  8  4  7   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1
6  8  3  1  4  6  5  5  7  5  5   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
7  4  5  5  9  5  4  8  6  6  1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1
```

Timings on given sample data and larger one -

```
In [17]: data = [[12,14,33,45,22,33,86,56],
    ...:         [78,12,52,1,99,22,4,19],
    ...:         [15,11,7,23,30,19,63,71],
    ...:         [2,14,52,36,17,95,8,39],
    ...:         [1,4,31,42,72,23,67,15],
    ...:         [92,28,32,52,77,19,55,10],
    ...:         [42,16,64,25,92,11,26,36],
    ...:         [12,21,38,17,90,32,41,74],
    ...:        ]
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['N1','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8'])

In [18]: %timeit presence_df(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 575 µs per loop

In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(1000,1000)))

In [20]: %timeit presence_df(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.86 ms per loop
```